# Can we know AWS EBS volumes detach date?

Tags: amazon-web-services, volume

Is there any way where we can check when(date) was an AWS EBS volume detached?

I have checked the AWS documentations but found nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have AWS CloudTrail active, you could look back at the audit history to see when an Amazon EBS volume was specifically detached.

It likely won't show detachments caused by terminations, but it will show specific requests to detach a volume.